# Proving a Lebesgue integral exists: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{2(e^x -1)}-\frac{1}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}\right)d\lambda(x)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can you tell me how I would go about proving that the Lebesgue integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{2(e^x -1)} - \frac{1}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}\right)d\lambda(x)$$ exists? I've already shown that $\dfrac{1}{2(e^x -1)} - \dfrac{1}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}$ is continuous over the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try showing that each term is Lebesgue integrable, separately. If both are, then the difference is.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on proving the second term is Lebesgue integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the given integral is *divergent* since the integrand, as $x \to 0^+$, admits the Laurent series expansion
$$
\frac{1}{2(e^x -1)} - \frac{1}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}=-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{2x}-\frac1{12}+O\left(x\right)
$$ which is not Lebesgue integrable over $(0,\pi/2)$.